# Is there a system setting to reduce nvidia-331 overheats when playing video (14.04)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, video, skype, overheating

I recently upgraded to 14.04 with the nvidia-331 driver (Dell Latitude E6430). The performance is lightning fast with the exception of playing video like YouTube or Skype. According to indicator-sensors the NVMS 5200 temperature rises right up to 95+ C (Other temperatures stay below 80), and indicator-cpufreq immediately reduces cpufreq to the minimum to cool the machine down. Consequently if I set off a video by accident, I have to suspend Ubuntu and let it cool for a few minutes to avoid moving at a snail's pace.

I love the performance of the driver otherwise, and would love to just tweak a system setting so that the card just paces itself a bit when Skyping or playing Flash, rather than revert drivers. Is there such a setting? I shouldn't have to buy a cooling fan to Skype just because of a driver upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the question is to switch off the nvidia-331 and nvidia-304 drivers, and use the Nouveau driver bundled with Ubuntu instead. Most online support does not advise the Nouveau driver so I was pleasantly surprised to see that it solved the problem perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Laptops often overheat when their graphics cards are used near capacity.  This is why gamers typically use cooling pads with them, and also why I recommend everyone use cooling pads all the time.  I will now give you not one but two solutions.

Buy a LARGE cooling pad wih one or two large diameter fans.  they can actually cost less than units with smaller fans, so don't gauge by price.

Clean the dust out of your laptop.  To do this, turn it off, hold it against your chest with the bottom of the laptop facing away from you and the exhaust port facing up.  Now place your mouth over the exhaust port sealing all the way around it.  Imagine you are trying to hit all the notes on a harmonica at once and blow hard into it, preferably with the lights on and your eyes open (goggles might be a good idea too)

You should see a plume of dust and even some dust bunnies pop out of the holes in the bottom of the laptop.  Repeat until no more dust comes out.

Before you ask, no, canned air is not better, especially in winter.  The moisture in your breath helps discharge static fields.  Also using your breath costs significantly less and is better for the environment.

Also if you or anyone you share a home with has allergies or asthma, please do this outdoors.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough reply, this is not what I was asking though, which was for a system setting related to the 331 driver. I will edit the title to clarify.

Comment: I get that, but seriously, slowing the machine down to prevent overheating is only a more practical solution than using a fan if you are either trying to operate on minimal power, ie off-grid, or you are operating in summer in a home which does not have air conditioning.

Comment: Open-mouth kissing my laptop? Can't decide if that's a -1 or a +1. Whatever happened to vacuums, compressed air & a rag? With the laptop off I'd be completely unconcerned about "air" static, much more concerned about spitting into my laptop (and licking months worth of grime off the bottom)

Comment: There's no shame in wiping the surface of the laptop before forcibly blowing into it.  The laptop won't be offended. Compressed air, as from an air compressor, can generate damaging static electricity, especially in winter when there is very little humidity to discharge it. If you fear you may spit, consult a friend or five, share my instructions with them.  Have them try it with their laptops, and when one of them comes back and thanks you, have that enthusiastic successful person blow yours.